# Error in column of a dataframe with R

Tags: r

I try to create a fucntion with R, but I get a problem with the positive.ponderate.polarity column of the subDF frame. The values are incorrect.
I think that the probleme comes from these lines :

**Edit2 :**

```
 if(any(unlist(strsplit(as.character(context), " ")) %in% booster_words))
               {
                   subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity <- subDF$positive.polarity * 3
               }
               else 
               {
                   subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity <- subDF$positive.polarity/3
               }

               # calculate the total polarity of the sentence and store in the vector
               polarity[i] <- sum(subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity) - sum(subDF$negative.polarity)
    }
```

Can you help me please?

Thank you

```
### function to calculate the polarity of sentences

calcPolarity <- function(sentiment_DF,sentences){
    booster_words <- c("more","enough", "a lot", "as")
    # separate each sentence in words using regular expression 
    # (it returns a list with the words of each sentence)
    sentencesSplitInWords <- regmatches(sentences,gregexpr("[[:word:]]+",sentences,perl=TRUE))

    # pre-allocate the polarity result vector with size = number of sentences
    polarity <- rep.int(0,length(sentencesSplitInWords))

    for(i in 1:length(polarity)){
        # get the i-th sentence words
        wordsOfASentence <- sentencesSplitInWords[[i]]

        # get the rows of sentiment_DF corresponding to the words in the sentence using match
        # N.B. if a word occurs twice, there will be two equal rows 
        # (but I think it's correct since in this way you count its polarity twice)
        subDF <- sentiment_DF[match(wordsOfASentence,sentiment_DF$word,nomatch = 0),]

        # extract a context of 3 words before the word in the dataframe

        context <- stringr::str_extract(sentences, "([^\\s]+\\s){3}subDF$word(\\s[^\\s]+){3}")
        # check there is a words of the context in the booster_words list
        if(any(unlist(strsplit(as.character(context), " ")) %in% booster_words))
               {
                   subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity <- 1.12
               }
               else 
               {
                   subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity <- 14
               }

               # calculate the total polarity of the sentence and store in the vector
               polarity[i] <- sum(subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity) - sum(subDF$negative.polarity)
    }
    return(polarity)
}
```

USAGE :

```
sentiment_DF <- data.frame(word=c('interesting','boring','pretty'),
                           positive.polarity=c(1,0,1),
                           negative.polarity=c(0,1,0))
sentences <- c("The course was interesting, but the professor was so boring.",
               "stackoverflow is an interesting place with interesting people!")
result <- calcPolarity(sentiment_DF,sentences)
```

**Edit**

I expect this result dataframe :

```
word   positive.polarity  nagative.polarity  positive.ponderate.polarity
interesting  1  0  1.12
boring  0  1  14
```

as result I expect to have 15.12(1.12+14) - 1 = 14.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New answer because this is the complete solution:

```
calcPolarity <- function(sentiment_DF,sentences){
  booster_words <- c("more","enough", "a lot", "as", "so")

  # pre-allocate the polarity result vector with size = number of sentences
  polarity <- rep.int(0,length(sentences))

  # loop per sentence
  for(i in 1:length(polarity)){
    sentence <- sentences[i]

    # separate each sentence in words using regular expression 
    wordsOfASentence <- unlist(regmatches(sentence,gregexpr("[[:word:]]+",sentence,perl=TRUE)))

    # get the rows of sentiment_DF corresponding to the words in the sentence using match
    # N.B. if a word occurs twice, there will be two equal rows 
    # (but I think it's correct since in this way you count its polarity twice)
    subDF <- sentiment_DF[match(wordsOfASentence,sentiment_DF$word,nomatch = 0),]


    # Find (number) of matching word. 
    wordOfInterest <- wordsOfASentence[which(wordsOfASentence %in% levels(sentiment_DF$word))]  # No multigrepl, so working with duplicates instead. eg interesting
    regexOfInterest <- paste0("([^\\s]+\\s){0,3}", wordOfInterest, "(\\s[^\\s]+){0,3}")

    # extract a context of 3 words before the word in the dataframe
    context <-  stringr::str_extract(sentence, regexOfInterest)
    names(context) <- wordOfInterest  # Helps in forloop

    contextValue <- function(context){
      ifelse(any(unlist(strsplit(context, " ")) %in% booster_words),  1.12, 14)
    }
    subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity <- sapply(context, contextValue)

    # Debug option
    print(subDF)

    # calculate the total polarity of the sentence and store in the vector
    polarity[i] <- sum(subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity) - sum(subDF$negative.polarity)

  }
  return(polarity)
}

sentiment_DF <- data.frame(word=c('interesting','boring','pretty'),
                           positive.polarity=c(1,0,1),
                           negative.polarity=c(0,1,0))
sentences <- c("The course was interesting, but the professor was so boring.",
               "stackoverflow is an interesting place with interesting people!")
result <- calcPolarity(sentiment_DF,sentences)
```

> It now print the tables discussed above. Outcomment this debug option

```
> result
[1] 14.12 28.00
```

Comment: I which you success with it. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much Jeremy and sorry to make you busy with my problem. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

what values do you expect? I reproduced your example and got:

```
> result  

[1] 27 28
```

Guessing into the blue I wonder that `subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity <- 14` is very high compared to `1.12`. Did you mean `1.4`?

**EDIT1**:
There's something going wrong in this line:

> `context <- stringr::str_extract(sentences, "([^\\s]+\\s){3}subDF$word(\\s[^\\s]+){3}")`

in general.... R takes the `subDF$word` within the regex literately. Try `paste0("([^\\s]+\\s){3}",subDF$word,"(\\s[^\\s]+){3}")` instead to hace a vector (length 2).

While debugging that expression I wounder what's that last part `(\\s[^\\s]+){3}` supposed to do. you only want the first three word, rigth?

**EDIT2:**
You have two vectors: (a) the list of regex to match and (b) the sentences themselves. Edit1 solves problem a. Using lapply solves problem b.

```
# extract a context of 3 words before the word in the dataframe
contexter <- function(sentence){
  stringr::str_extract(sentence, paste0("([^\\s]+\\s){3}",subDF$word))
}
context <- lapply(sentences, contexter)
```

**EDIT3:**
This work in progress... This should bringing you closer to where you want to be:

```
# Add a booster word occurring in sentences at all
booster_words <- c("more","enough", "a lot", "as", "so")

# extract a context of 3 words before the word in the dataframe
contexter <- function(sentence){
  context <- stringr::str_extract(sentence, paste0("([^\\s]+\\s){3}",subDF$word))

  # check there is a words of the context in the booster_words list
  if(any(unlist(strsplit(context, " ")) %in% booster_words))
  {
    subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity <- 1.12
  }
  else 
  {
    subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity <- 14
  }

  return(subDF)
}

polarity <- lapply(sentences, contexter)
```

Returns:

```
> polarity
[[1]]
word positive.polarity negative.polarity positive.ponderate.polarity
1 interesting                 1                 0                        1.12
2      boring                 0                 1                        1.12

[[2]]
word positive.polarity negative.polarity positive.ponderate.polarity
1 interesting                 1                 0                          14
2      boring                 0                 1                          14
```